# AJAX : How can I use beforeSend function in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, ajax

I want to change button text and state(ex: disabled) when I click on it. How can I implement it using beforeSend in  XMLHttpRequest?

```
const form = document.querySelector(".request form"),
  continueBtn = form.querySelector(".button input"),
  errorText = form.querySelector(".error-text"),
  successText = form.querySelector(".success-text");
form.onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); //Preventing form from submitting
};
continueBtn.onclick = () => {
  //let' s start ajax
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //creating xml object
  xhr.open("POST", "phpControllers/signup.php", true);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        let data = xhr.response;
        if (data === "success") {
          location.href = "index.php";
        } else {
          errorText.innerHTML = data;
          errorText.style.display = "block";
          successText.textContent = data;
          successText.style.display = "none";
        }
        console.log(data);
      }
    }
  };
  //we have to send the form data through ajax to php
  let formData = new FormData(form); //creating new formData Object
  xhr.send(formData); //sending the data to php
};
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML to support this question please?

Comment: Just execute what ever code you need before you call `xhr.send()`?